# How can I read line by line from a variable in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, io, cat

I have a variable which contains multiline output of a command. What's the most effecient way to read the output line by line from the variable?

For example:

```
jobs="$(jobs)"
if [ "$jobs" ]; then
    # read lines from $jobs
fi
```

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You can use a while loop with process substitution:

```
while read -r line
do
    echo "$line"
done < <(jobs)
```

An optimal way to read a multiline variable is to set a blank `IFS` variable and `printf` the variable in with a trailing newline:

```
# Printf '%s\n' "$var" is necessary because printf '%s' "$var" on a
# variable that doesn't end with a newline then the while loop will
# completely miss the last line of the variable.
while IFS= read -r line
do
   echo "$line"
done < <(printf '%s\n' "$var")
```

Note: As per [shellcheck sc2031](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2031), the use of process substition is preferable to a pipe to avoid [subtly] creating an subshell.

Also, please realize that by naming the variable `jobs` it may cause confusion since that is also the name of a common shell command.

Comment: If you want to keep all your whitespace, then use `while IFS= read` .... If you want to prevent \ interpretation, then use `read -r`

Comment: I've fixed the points fred.bear mentioned, as well as changed `echo` to `printf %s`, so that your script would work even with non-tame input.

Comment: To read from a multiline variable, a herestring is preferable to piping from printf (see l0b0's answer).

Comment: @ata Though I've heard this "preferable" often enough, it must be noted that a herestring always requires the `/tmp` directory to be writable, as it relies on being able to create a temporary work file. Should you ever find yourself on a restricted system with `/tmp` being read-only (and not changeable by you), you will be happy about the possibility of using an alternate solution, e. g. with the `printf` pipe.

Comment: @syntaxerror many thanks for the info, it's good to know!

Comment: You're welcome. TBH, I've been through this "hell" once before you, to know more see [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98606/bash-some-issue-when-using-read-variable-on-a-read-only-root-partition-a).

Comment: In the second example, if the multi-line variable doesn't contain a trailing newline you will loose the last element.   Change it to: `printf "%s\n" "$var" | while IFS= read -r line`

Comment: @DavidH.Bennett Your method prevents losing the last line, but it also manipulates the original variable. When processing the last line, it is not known whether or not it originally had the trailing newline. This might or might not be acceptable (for me, it wouldn't be). Furthermore, if the last line already has a trailing newline, it will be doubled, causing an empty bogus line being processed at the end. IMHO, the `read` based solutions can't work cleanly, unless wrapped into a lot of additional ugly code.

Answer (score 49):

To process the output of a command line by line ([explanation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18886/why-is-while-ifs-read-used-so-often-instead-of-ifs-while-read)):

```
jobs |
while IFS= read -r line; do
  process "$line"
done
```

If you have the data in a variable already:

```
printf %s "$foo" | …
```

`printf %s "$foo"` is almost identical to `echo "$foo"`, but prints `$foo` literally, whereas `echo "$foo"` might interpret `$foo` as an option to the echo command if it begins with a `-`, and might expand backslash sequences in `$foo` in some shells.

Note that in some shells (ash, bash, pdksh, but not ksh or zsh), the right-hand side of a pipeline runs in a separate process, so any variable you set in the loop is lost. For example, the following line-counting script prints 0 in these shells:

```
n=0
printf %s "$foo" |
while IFS= read -r line; do
  n=$(($n + 1))
done
echo $n
```

A workaround is to put the remainder of the script (or at least the part that needs the value of `$n` from the loop) in a command list:

```
n=0
printf %s "$foo" | {
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    n=$(($n + 1))
  done
  echo $n
}
```

---

If acting on the non-empty lines is good enough and the input is not huge, you can use word splitting:

```
IFS='
'
set -f
for line in $(jobs); do
  # process line
done
set +f
unset IFS
```

Explanation: setting `IFS` to a single newline makes word splitting occur at newlines only (as opposed to any whitespace character under the default setting). `set -f` turns off globbing (i.e. wildcard expansion), which would otherwise happen to the result of a command substitution `$(jobs)` or a variable substitution `$foo`. The `for` loop acts on all the pieces of `$(jobs)`, which are all the non-empty lines in the command output. Finally, restore the globbing and `IFS` settings to values that are equivalent to the defaults.

Comment: I have had trouble with setting IFS and unsetting IFS. I think the right thing to do is store the old value of IFS and set IFS back to that old value. I'm not a bash expert, but in my experience, this gets you back to the original bahavior.

Comment: @BjornRoche: inside a function, use `local IFS=something`.  It won't affect the global-scope value.  IIRC, `unset IFS` doesn't get you back to the default (and certainly doesn't work if it wasn't the default beforehand).

Comment: I am wondering whether using `set` in the way shown in the last example is correct. The code snippet assumes that `set +f` was active at the begin, and therefore restores that setting at the end. However, this assumption might be wrong. What if `set -f` was active at the beginning?

Comment: @Binarus I only restore settings equivalent to the defaults. Indeed, if you want to restore the original settings, you need to do more work. For `set -f`, save the original `$-`. For `IFS`, it's annoyingly fiddly if you don't have `local` and you want to support the unset case; if you do want to restore it, I recommend enforcing the invariant that `IFS` remains set.

Comment: Using `local` would indeed be the best solution, because `local -` makes the shell options local, and `local IFS` makes `IFS` local. Unfortunately, `local` is only valid within functions, which makes code restructuring necessary. Your suggestion to introduce the policy that `IFS` is always set also sounds very reasonable and solves the biggest part of the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Binarus `local` doesn't exist in all sh variants, and `local -` requires a very recent bash.

Answer (score 28):

```
jobs="$(jobs)"
while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo "$line"
done <<< "$jobs"
```

References:

- [Here strings](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/x13320.html)
- [`while`](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/loops1.html#WHILELOOPREF)
- [`IFS`](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/internalvariables.html#IFSREF)
- [`read`](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/internal.html#READREF)

Comment: `-r` is a good idea too; It prevents `\\` interpretation... (it is in your links, but its probably worth mentioning, just to round out your `IFS=` (which is essential to prevent losing whitespace)

Comment: Only this solution worked for me. Thanks brah.

Comment: Doesn't this solution suffer from the same problem which is mentioned in the comments to @dogbane's answer? What if the last line of the variable is not terminated by a newline character?

Comment: This answer provides the cleanest way to feed the content of a variable to the `while read` construct.

Answer (score 21):

Problem: if you use while loop it will run in subshell and all variables will be lost.
Solution: use for loop

```
# change delimiter (IFS) to new line.
IFS_BAK=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'

for line in $variableWithSeveralLines; do
 echo "$line"

 # return IFS back if you need to split new line by spaces:
 IFS=$IFS_BAK
 IFS_BAK=
 lineConvertedToArraySplittedBySpaces=( $line )
 echo "{lineConvertedToArraySplittedBySpaces[0]}"
 # return IFS back to newline for "for" loop
 IFS_BAK=$IFS
 IFS=$'\n'

done 

# return delimiter to previous value
IFS=$IFS_BAK
IFS_BAK=
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!  All of the above solutions failed for me.

Comment: piping into a `while read` loop in bash means the while loop is in a subshell, so variables aren't global.  `while read;do ;done <<< "$var"` makes the loop body not a subshell.  (Recent bash has an option to put the body of a `cmd | while` loop not in a subshell, like ksh has always had.)

Comment: Also see [this related post](http://serverfault.com/q/259339/313521).

Comment: In similar situations, I found it surprisingly difficult to treat `IFS` correctly. This solution has a problem as well: What if `IFS` is not set at all in the beginning (i.e. is undefined)? It will be defined in every case after that code snippet; this doesn't seem to be correct.

Answer (score 9):

In recent bash versions, use `mapfile` or `readarray` to efficiently read command output into arrays

```
$ readarray test < <(ls -ltrR)
$ echo ${#test[@]}
6305
```

Disclaimer: horrible example, but you can prolly come up with a better command to use than ls yourself

Comment: It's a nice way, but litters /var/tmp with temporary files on my system. +1 anyway

Comment: @eugene: that's funny. What system (distro/OS) is that on?

Comment: It's FreeBSD 8. How to reproduce: put `readarray` in a function and call the function a few times.

Comment: Nice one, @sehe. +1

Answer (score 1):

The common patterns to solve this issue have been given in the other answers.

However, I'd like to add my approach, although I am not sure how efficient it is. But it is (at least for me) quite understandable, does not alter the original variable (all solutions which use `read` must have the variable in question with a trailing newline and therefore add it, which alters the variable), does not create subshells (which all pipe-based solutions do), does not use here-strings (which have their own issues), and does not use process substitution (nothing against it, but a bit hard to understand sometimes).

Actually, I don't understand why `bash`'s integrated REs are used so rarely. Perhaps they are not portable, but since the OP has used the `bash` tag, that won't stop me :-)

```
#!/bin/bash

function ProcessLine() {

  printf '%s' "$1"
}


function ProcessText1() {

  local Text=$1
  local Pattern=$'^([^\n]*\n)(.*)$'

  while [[ "$Text" =~ $Pattern ]]; do

    ProcessLine "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    Text="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"

  done

  ProcessLine "$Text"
}


function ProcessText2() {

  local Text=$1
  local Pattern=$'^([^\n]*\n)(.*)$'

  while [[ "$Text" =~ $Pattern ]]; do

    ProcessLine "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    Text="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"

  done
}


function ProcessText3() {

  local Text=$1
  local Pattern=$'^([^\n]*\n?)(.*)$'

  while [[ ("$Text" != '') &&
           ("$Text" =~ $Pattern) ]]; do

    ProcessLine "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    Text="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"

  done
}


MyVar1=$'a1\nb1\nc1\n'
MyVar2=$'a2\n\nb2\nc2'
MyVar3=$'a3\nb3\nc3'

ProcessText1 "$MyVar1"
ProcessText1 "$MyVar2"
ProcessText1 "$MyVar3"
```

Output:

```
root@cerberus:~/scripts# ./test4
a1
b1
c1
a2

b2
c2a3
b3
c3root@cerberus:~/scripts#
```

A few notes:

The behavior depends on what variant of `ProcessText` you use. In the example above, I have used `ProcessText1`.

Note that

- `ProcessText1` keeps newline characters at the end of lines
- `ProcessText1` processes the last line of the variable (which contains the text `c3`) *although that line does not contain a trailing newline character.* Because of the missing trailing newline, the command prompt after the script execution is appended to the last line of the variable without being separated from the output.
- `ProcessText1` always considers the part between the last newline in the variable and the end of the variable as a line, even if it is empty; of course, that line, whether empty or not, does not have a trailing newline character. That is, even if the last character in the variable is a newline, `ProcessText1` will treat the empty part (null string) between that last newline and the end of the variable as a (yet empty) line and will pass it to line processing. You can easily prevent this behavior by wrapping the second call to `ProcessLine` into an appropriate check-if-empty condition; however, I think it is more logical to leave it as-is.

`ProcessText1` needs to call `ProcessLine` at two places, which might be uncomfortable if you would like to place a block of code there which directly processes the line, instead of calling a function which processes the line; you would have to repeat the code which is error-prone.

In contrast, `ProcessText3` processes the line or calls the respective function only at one place, making replacing the function call by a code block a no-brainer. This comes at the cost of two `while` conditions instead of one. Apart from the implementation differences, `ProcessText3` behaves exactly the same as `ProcessText1`, except that it does not consider the part between the last newline character in the variable and the end of the variable as line if that part is empty. That is, `ProcessText3` will not go into line processing after the last newline character of the variable if that newline character is the last character in the variable.

`ProcessText2` works like `ProcessText1`, except that lines must have a trailing newline character. That is, the part between the last newline character in the variable and the end of the variable is *not* considered to be a line and is silently thrown away. Consequently, if the variable does not contain any newline character, no line processing happens at all.

I like that approach more than the other solutions shown above, but probably I have missed something (not being very experienced in `bash` programming, and not being interested in other shells very much).

Answer (score 0):

You can use <<< to simply read from the variable containing the newline-separated data:

```
while read -r line
do 
  echo "A line of input: $line"
done <<<"$lines"
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix&Linux!  This essentially duplicates an answer from four years ago.  Please don’t post an answer unless you have something new to contribute.