# Why is `while IFS= read` used so often, instead of `IFS=; while read..`?

Tags: shell, text-processing, environment-variables

It seems that normal practice would put the setting of IFS outside the while loop in order to not repeat setting it for each iteration... Is this just a habitual "monkey see, monkey do" style, as it has been for this monkey until I read *man read*, or am I missing some subtle (or blatantly obvious) trap here?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

The trap is that

```
IFS=; while read..
```

sets the `IFS` for the whole shell environment outside the loop, whereas

```
while IFS= read
```

redefines it only for the **`read` invocation** (except in the Bourne shell).
You can check that doing a loop like

```
while IFS= read xxx; ... done
```

then after such loop, `echo "blabalbla $IFS ooooooo"` prints

```
blabalbla
 ooooooo
```

whereas after

```
IFS=; read xxx; ... done
```

the `IFS` **stays** redefined: now `echo "blabalbla $IFS ooooooo"` prints

```
blabalbla  ooooooo
```

So if you use the second form, you have to remember to reset : `IFS=$' \t\n'`.

---

<sub>The second part of this question [has been merged here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18922/in-while-ifs-read-why-does-ifs-have-no-effect), so I've removed the related answer from here.</sub>

Comment: Okay, it **seems** that a potential 'trap' is to neglect to reset the outer IFS... But I do wonder if there is also something else afoot... I've be testing things here, pretty feverishly, and I've notice that setting IFS in while's command list behaves qute differently, depending whether or not it is followed by a colon.  I don't understand this behaviour (yet), and I now wonder if there is some special consideration involved at this level... eg. `while IFS=X read` doesn't split at `X`, but `while IFS=X; read` does...

Comment: (You meant *semi*colon, right?) The second `while` does not make much sense - the condition for `while` **ends** at that semicolon, so there is no actual loop... `read` becomes just the first command inside the one-element loop... Or not? What about the `do` then..?

Comment: No, wait - you're right, you can have several commands in the `while` condition (before `do`).

Comment: Oh.. definitely, you can have them... as you've realised... but they seem to not like the semi-colon... (and the loop will keep looping ad-infinitum until the last command returns a non-zero exit code)... I'm now wondering if the **trap** lies in a different sector entirely; that of understanding how *while's* command list works, eg. why does `IFS=` work, but `IFS=X` doesn't... (or maybe I've OD'd on this for a while.. coffee break needed :)

Comment: `IFS= read ...` sets the IFS variable **only** for the duration of the read command itself. For example `foo=bar sh -c 'echo $foo'` returns "bar", but then typing `echo $foo` returns an empty string.

Comment: @glenn jackman: All the things mentioned so far make sense in their own right, but they seem to clash with what I am actually observing... (see update to my question) ... Maybe that will clarify my quandary....

Comment: I've shuffled my update to [another question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18922/in-while-ifs-read-why-does-ifs-have-no-effect)... The issues are related, but the focus is diferent

Comment: $rozcietrzewiacz.. Oops... I hadn't noticed your update, when I moved my update (as mentioned in prev comment)..  It looks interesting, and it is *starting* to make sense... but even for a night-bird like me, it is extremely late...(I just heard the morning birds :)...  That said, I've rallied a bit and read your examples... I think I've got it, actually I'm sure you've got it, but I must sleep :) ... This is almost a Eureka! moment... thanks

Comment: Considering this : `while IFS=':' read …` is the IFS variable reset to `:` string on each loop ? Like will IFS value be restored to `:` if I alter it inside the loop as well ? `while IFS=':' read -r pth ; do ; IFS='/' list=($pth); echo test; done < file.txt` ?

Comment: the answer states imprecisely _"shell environment outside the loop,"_ to a reader it would seem to mean in opposition to "inside the loop". **It is not**. First example "sets...environment outside AND inside the loop," or "sets the IFS for the scope which is the same inside and outside of the loop". @Stphane No, in `while IFS=':' read …` IFS variable is not **reset**, but overriden, and **only** for the `read` build-in. And if you set IFS inside the loop, you did set it also for outside. Check the Gilles answer, it explains this more precisely.

Answer (score 57):

Let's look at an example, with some carefully-crafted input text:

```
text=' hello  world\
foo\bar'
```

That's two lines, the first beginning with a space and ending with a backslash. First, let's look at what happens without any precautions around [`read`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/read.html) (but using `printf '%s\n' "$text"` to carefully print `$text` without any risk of expansion). (Below, `$ ‌` is the shell prompt.)

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$text" |
  while read line; do printf '%s\n' "[$line]"; done
[hello worldfoobar]
```

`read` ate up the backslashes: backslash-newline causes the newline to be ignored, and backslash-anything ignores that first backslash. To avoid backslashes being treated specially, we use `read -r`.

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$text" |
  while read -r line; do printf '%s\n' "[$line]"; done
[hello  world\]
[foo\bar]
```

That's better, we have two lines as expected. The two lines almost contain the desired content: the double space between `hello` and `world` has been retained, because it's within the `line` variable. On the other hand, the initial space was eaten up. That's because `read` reads as many words as you pass it variables, except that the last variable contains the rest of the line — but it still starts with the first word, i.e. the initial spaces are discarded.

So, in order to read each line literally, we need to make sure that no [word splitting](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_05) is going on. We do this by setting the [`IFS` variable](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_05_03) to an empty value.

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$text" |
  while IFS= read -r line; do printf '%s\n' "[$line]"; done
[ hello  world\]
[foo\bar]
```

Note how we set `IFS` **specifically for the duration of the `read` built-in**. The `IFS= read -r line` sets the environment variable `IFS` (to an empty value) specifically for the execution of `read`.
This is an instance of the general [simple command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_01) syntax: a (possibly empty) sequence of variable assignments followed by a command name and its arguments (also, you can throw in redirections at any point). Since `read` is a built-in, the variable never actually ends up in an external process's environment; nonetheless the value of `$IFS` is what we're assigning there as long as `read` is executing¹. Note that `read` is not a [special built-in](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_14), so the assignment does last only for its duration.

Thus we're taking care not to change the value of `IFS` for other instructions that may rely on it. This code will work no matter what the surrounding code has set `IFS` to initially, and it will not cause any trouble if the code inside the loop relies on `IFS`.

Contrast with this code snippet, which looks files up in a colon-separated path. The list of file names is read from a file, one file name per line.

```
IFS=":"; set -f
while IFS= read -r name; do
  for dir in $PATH; do
    ## At this point, "$IFS" is still ":"
    if [ -e "$dir/$name" ]; then echo "$dir/$name"; fi
  done
done <filenames.txt
```

If the loop was `while IFS=; read -r name; do …`, then `for dir in $PATH` would not split `$PATH` into colon-separated components. If the code was `IFS=; while read …`, it would be even more obvious that `IFS` is not set to `:` in the loop body.

Of course, it would be possible to restore the value of `IFS` after executing `read`. But that would require knowing the previous value, which is extra effort. `IFS= read` is the simple way (and, conveniently, also the shortest way).

¹  <sub>And, if `read` is interrupted by a trapped signal, possibly while the trap is executing — this is not specified by POSIX and depends on the shell in practice.</sub>

Comment: Thanks Gilles.. a very nice guided tour..(did you mean 'set -f'?).... Now, for the reader, to restate what has already been said, I'd like to emphasise the issue which had me looking at it the wrong way. First and foremost is the fact that the construct `while IFS= read` (without a semi-colon after `=`) is **not** a special form of `while` or of `IFS` or of `read`.. The construct is generic: ie. `anyvar=anyvalue anycommand`. The lack of `;` after setting `anyvar` makes the scope of `anyvar` *local* to `anycommand`.. The while--do/done loop is 100% *unrelated* to the local scope of `any_var`.

Answer (score 5):

Apart from the (already clarified) `IFS` scoping differences between the `while IFS='' read`, `IFS=''; while read` and `while IFS=''; read` idioms (per-command vs script/shell-wide `IFS` variable scoping), the take-home lesson is that you lose the leading **and** trailing spaces of an input line if the IFS variable is set to (contain a) space.

This can have pretty serious consequences if file paths are being processed.

Therefore setting the IFS variable to the empty string is anything but a bad idea since it ensures that a line's leading and trailing whitespace does not get stripped.

See also: [Bash, read line by line from file, with IFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385772/bash-read-line-by-line-from-file-with-ifs)

```
(
shopt -s nullglob
touch '  file with spaces   '
IFS=$' \t\n' read -r file <<<"$(printf '%s' *file*with*spaces*)"
ls -l "$file"
IFS='' read -r file <<<"$(printf '%s' *file*with*spaces*)"
ls -l "$file"
)
```

Comment: +1 excellent demonstration, cleanup after with 'rm \*file\*with\*spaces\*'

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [**Yuzem’s answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2608159)

If you want to set `IFS` to an actual character, this worked for me

```
iconv -f cp1252 zapni.tv.php | while IFS='#' read -d'#' line
do
  echo "$line"
done
```