# How to iterate over two sets of iterables in a shell script?

Tags: shell-script

Usually when I write a shell script for a specific task, I just make a list of files like so:

```
#/bin/sh
read -d '' imagefiles <<EOF

./01/IMG0000.jpg
./01/IMG0001.jpg
./01/IMG0002.jpg
./01/IMG0003.jpg
./01/IMG0004.jpg
./01/IMG0005.jpg
./01/IMG0006.jpg
./01/IMG0007.jpg
(a whole bunch of files down to ./10/IMG0102.jpg)

EOF

for i in $imagefiles
  for j in range(len(commands))
do

mv $i ./$j.jpg

  done
done
```

In this instance I wanted to be able to iterate over the output of `seq` but following Gilles's suggestion simply wrote that part out of it out as Python (yeah I know that as it is it would execute each command j times, leading to about 100000 executions). Earlier on in the day I was renaming 736 files in sequence, but now I'm renaming 1000-odd files. I'm sure there's a better way to do that (please don't hesitate to tell me), but it would still be nice to know how to iterate over the list of commands and some other iterable.

Comment: Why do you need `seq`.. can't you just increment a number each time you process a file name?

Comment: Your example code iterating over a list of commands is incomplete and I'm not quite sure I see the purpose or now it is supposed to interact with your sequence. Could you be more specific?

Comment: ixtmixilix, when you ask a question about shell scripting, it is very helpful to indicate what shell you are using (use `echo $SHELL` for example if you are not sure). Or otherwise, say that you are interested in a portable solution.

Comment: Done. (See updated answer).

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. What does “iterate over two sets of iterables” mean? Explain what you want the script to do. In a pinch, even Python code would be better than nothing.

Comment: @Gilles amending question now...

Comment: @Gilles done amending. i used python where i didn't know how to write stuff. good suggestion.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the word "commands" right? It looks like you are stuffing it full of data to operate ON not commands to operate on data WITH.

Comment: @caleb true. good point.

Comment: I think that mistake has sent people off hunting in the wrong direction and made some of the answers more complicated than they need to be. If you fix it things might start getting simplified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so you want to zip two iterables, or in other words you want a single loop, iterating over a bunch of strings, with an additional counter. It's quite easy to implement a counter.

```
n=0
for x in $commands; do
  mv -- "$x" "$n.jpg"
  n=$(($n+1))
done
```

Note that this only works if none of the elements that you're iterating over contains any whitespace (nor globbing characters). If you have items separated by newlines, turn off globbing and split only on newlines.

```
n=0
IFS='
'; set -f
for x in $commands; do
  mv -- "$x" "$n.jpg"
  n=$(($n+1))
done
set +f; unset IFS
```

If you only need to iterate over the data once, loop around `read` (see [Why is `while IFS= read` used so often, instead of `IFS=; while read..`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18886/why-is-while-ifs-read-used-so-often-instead-of-ifs-while-read/18936#18936) for more explanations).

```
n=0
while IFS= read -r x; do
  mv -- "$x" "$n.jpg"
  n=$(($n+1))
done <<EOF
…
EOF
```

If you're using a shell that has arrays (bash, ksh or zsh), store the elements in an array. In zsh, either run `setopt ksh_arrays` to number array elements from 0, or adapt the code for array element numbering starting at 1.

```
commands=(
    ./01/IMG0000.jpg
    …
)
n=0
while [[ $n -lt ${#commands} ]]; do
  mv -- "${commands[$n]}" "$n.jpg"
done
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can iterate over multiple things in parallel in bash.

I would start out `i=1`. then iterate over your list of files and include `let i=$i+1` in the loop. Also include a test to break out of the loop if `$i -ge 736` if you want to quit iterating over whatever your input is after that number of loops.

```
i=0
for file in ./{01..10}/*jpg; do
    let i=$i+1
    mv "$file" "$i-$file"
done
```

If you were trying to quite after X number of files you could use a test like this:

```
[[ $i -ge 736 ]] && return || let i=$i+1
```

Answer (score 3):

If your shell is `bash`, you don't need to run the `seq` program. Just use

```
for i in {1..736}
  do
```

If you want a sequence with leading zeros, just use `{001..736}` (or even `{0001..0736}`) instead.

Also, when possible, try not to use backticks ([see this question for how it can mess things up](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/whats-the-difference-between-stuff-and-stuff)).

Another thing is, when you want to operate on a set of files you might find this useful:

```
for file in /some/path/*
  do
```

Which will operate on all the files *(and folders)* in the directory `/some/path/`. To narrow this down to files only, you can use a test like `[ -f "$file" ]`, for example

```
for file in /some/path/*
  do
  [ -f "$file" ] || continue
  (do your stuff here)
```

Furthermore, the construct `/some/path/*` can be tuned by shell patterns like `/some/path[123]/*`, `/some/path[A-Z]/b*[e-g]*`, `/some/path{1,5,23}/*` etc.

As far as the first part of your question is concerned, you can just use a nested `for` (or `while` or any) loop like this:

```
for cm in $commands; do
 for file in /some/path[ab]{1,4,2}/*.log; do
    mv "${file}" "${file//text/replacement}"
 done
done
```

Answer (score -4):

bash supports arrays:

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html

OR

```
COUNT=0
for i in `ls *.txt`
do
  COUNT=`expr $COUNT + 1`
  mv "$i" "$COUNT-$i"
done
```

This would rename files a.txt b.txt c.txt to 1-a.txt 2-b.txt 3-c.txt.

Comment: Can you give a demonstration of how arrays could make this particularly scripting issue easier / faster / more elegant?

Comment: Arrays would answer the question of "How to iterate over two sets of iterables in a shell script?" (which kind of differed from the explanation of the problem). if you increment COUNT, then you could manage ${ARRAY1[$COUNT]} ${ARRAY2[$COUNT]} and ${ARRAY3[$COUNT]} in the same seq 1 10 loop for instance. For the explanation of the problem, I would use the "for i in ls" solution.

Comment: Don't parse the output of `ls` like that! The shell globing will handle that correctly, using `ls` will break it!

Comment: If you're using bash, this approach to incrementing a variable can be done within the shell: `(( COUNT++ ))`

Comment: dont use "for i in *.txt". Use for i in `ls *.txt` so that you can filter out stuff you dont want. Like `ls *.txt | grep -v badfile.txt`... more often than not, it is more more complicated then just *.txt.

Comment: The reported example is one of the reason to stay away from ABS.

Comment: No, Caleb is right. [Don't parse the output of `ls`.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) It doesn't work. Also, unless you're running on an antique, use shell arithmetic, you don't need `expr` any more.