# Reading two files into an IFS while loop -- Is there a way to get a zero diff result in this case?

Tags: text-processing, shell-script, awk, diff

I have a text file full of several hundred lines of sequences like this:

```
    b 29.
    b 52.
    c 84.
    c 83.
    c 94.
    c 93.
    c 61.
    b 38.
    c 81.
    c 92.
    c 28.
    c 37.
    c 27.

    lara@batcuter:~/.asd/a-new-way-of-studying-go$ wc -l game7
    271 game7
```

and the following script, which separates a text file into two files, one of which consists of odd-numbered lines and one of which consists of even-numbered lines, then reads both files into a while IFS loop, printing a line from each at a time:

```
#/bin/bash
#testing liquor-where-twin-twas-born

awk '{print>"line-"NR%2}' $@

while IFS= read -r lineA && IFS= read -r lineB <&3; do
  echo "$lineA";
  echo "$lineB" 
done <line-1 3<line-0
```

which unfortunately gives something not quite the same as the input file, due to the fact that one file was one line longer than the other.

```
    lara@batcuter:~/.asd/a-new-way-of-studying-go$ testing-liquor game7 > test
    lara@batcuter:~/.asd/a-new-way-of-studying-go$ diff test game7
    270a271
    > b 7.
```

Obviously, since the file is 271 lines long, splitting it in half yields two files, one of which is 136 lines, and one of which is 135 lines. I need to fix the IFS while loop to return zero differences. At first, I thought using `read ... || read ...` would help. But actually, that just bloated the output, inserting more than a single a newline between each entry, and shaving off the last line (the line that ended up in the file with the odd number of lines), as did all the other solutions I tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tell [the person who suggested `||`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/26605/2) that he's an idiot. Using `||` makes the snippet read all the lines from `fileA` first, then all the lines from `fileB`, because as long as `read lineA` returns true, `read lineB` is not executed. Instead, call `read` both times, saving the return status, then test the return statuses.

```
while
    IFS= read -r lineA; statusA=$?
    IFS= read -r lineB; statusB=$?
    [ $statusA -eq 0 ] || [ $statusB -eq 0 ]
do …
```

You can go on to test `$statusA` and `$statusB` inside the loop if you need to know whether a file has run out (the line contents will be empty, but this is not distinguishable from an empty line).