# How to copy rows of different files and paste column-wise?

Tags: text-processing, awk, python

I want to create a new file by copying rows of each file and pasting columnwise according to their file name orders. 
Here is the sample input and required output files below.

file1.txt

```
1234
5678
9201140
```

file2.txt

```
abcged
ghigk
lmn
```

required output file

out.tx

```
1234
abcged
5678
ghigk
9201140
lmn
```

Comment: A similar question is answered [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26601/17666), but with focus on shell processing.

Answer (score 4):

Simply `paste`:

```
paste -d'\n' file1.txt file2.txt
```

If you want to use `awk`, you can:

```
awk '{getline a < "file2.txt";printf "%s\n%s\n", $0, a}' file1.txt
```