# Load files from different directories one after the other

Tags: bash

I have a script in bash that transfer csv files to a python program from 2 differents directories like so :

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR1=/a/directory
DIR2=/another/directory

for f in DIR1
do
    /direc/to/python3.7 /dir/scriptspython/.py $DIR1/$f
done

for n in DIR2
do
    /direc/to/python3.7 /dir/scriptspython/.py $DIR2/$f
done
```

The problem is that i'd like the files from the directories to load one after the other like so : `$DIR1/$f(1) then $DIR2/$n(1)...$DIR1/$f(x) then DIR2/$n(x)`

My problem looks similar to this [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26601/how-to-read-from-two-input-files-using-while-loop) but with directories instead of files

Comment: Please clarify: Are `DIR1` and `DIR2` already populated with CSV files you wish to send to your Python script as parameters, or is the Python script creating CSV files you wish to place into `DIR1` and `DIR2`?

Comment: DIR1 and DIR2 are already populated with CSV files, I specify to the python script the path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I assume you have files like this

```
aa/apple aa/orange aa/perry  bb/apple bb/orange bb/perry
```

We could use `aa/*` and `bb/*` to list the files in both directories, then save them in two arrays, and loop over those:

```
#!/bin/bash
files1=(aa/*)
files2=(bb/*)
for (( i=0; i < ${#files1[@]}; i++)); do
    echo "${files1[i]}"
    echo "${files2[i]}"
done
```

That would output them in the order `aa/apple`, `bb/apple`, `aa/orange`, etc. The sort order is the default lexicographic sort. The above takes the file count from the first list, so it basically assumes there is an equal number of files in both directories.

(I'm not sure how much sense any of this makes if the lists of filenames aren't equal in the two directories.)

Comment: I haven't got the same number of files in both directory so I think that'll save the number of loops stored in i and then finish uploading the rest starting from i.