# What is the meaning of "<&3" and "done < file11 3< file22"

Tags: shell, io-redirection, read

I have the following script:

```
while read lineA && read lineB <&3
do
    echo "$lineA"
    echo "$lineB"
    echo
done < file11 3< file22
```

This code is working fine. But I don't understand these:

- `<&3`
- `done < file11 3< file22`

Comment: Could you explain us what does the script? (You say it's working fine)

Answer (score 23):

The script reads pairs of strings from two files.  In each iteration, it reads a string from `file11` into `lineA`, and from `file22` into `lineB`.  It does this until it encounters the end of either file.  The body of the loop outputs the two strings and a blank line.

The `<file11` means "connect/redirect standard input from `file11` into this command", where "this command" is the `while` loop. This could also have been written `0<file11`.

Standard input is file descriptor number 0.   File descriptors 1 and 2 are reserved for the standard output and standard error streams.

The `3<file22` means "connect file descriptor 3 to `file22` for this command".  The number 3 happens to be the next "free" file descriptor number, but the code could have used 4 or 5 or any small integer other than 0, 1 and 2 instead (the limit of the usable file descriptor numbers depends on what shell is being used, but numbers up to 9 are guaranteed to work).

In the loop, `read lineA` will read a string from standard input by default, i.e. from the file `file11` (standard input is inherited from the loop).  This could also have been written `read lineA <&0`.

With `read lineB <&3`, the `read` command reads from file descriptor 3, i.e. from `file22`, rather than from standard input (file descriptor 3 is available in the loop, just like standard input is).

In short, it uses the standard input stream and an "extra" file descriptor (number 3) to read from two files "simultaneously" (a string at a time from each file in turn).  Usually, one only have access to *one* input stream, but this bypasses that restriction by explicitly creating a second input stream and connecting it to the `file22` file.

Related:

- [How to read from two input files using while loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26601)

---

I use the word "string" above rather than "line". The things read from the two files will have flanking whitespaces stripped off, and certain escape sequences will be interpreted specially.

To read a *line* using `read`, use

```
IFS= read -r varname
```

Related:

- [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123)

Comment: Good answer! What I don't understand is how file descriptor 3 can be used. Does this mean than `3<file22` is like a `fopen` where the `FID` is not returned but pre-specified?

Comment: @A.Donda You are describing `fdopen()`. Yes.