# In bash, feed output of one command line-by-line into another command

Tags: bash

I have the following bash command which fetches and block XML from a single column in mysql and feeds it into xmllint to prettify it.

```
mysql --format csv --skip-column-names -e "select xmldata from mytable limit 1;" | xmllint --format -
```

So far so good, but it only works for one row at a time. I would like to adapt this so each line in the SQL query output is fed in to a separate call to xmlint.

I know this can be done with a loop in a bash script -- but I'd like to do it in a one-liner if possible. Supposedly this can be done with xargs but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
mysql --format csv --skip-column-names \
    -e "select xmldata from mytable limit 1;" \
    | while IFS= read -r line; do xmllint --format - <<<"$line"; done
```

Split for easier reading, obviously you don't need to.  The `<<<$line` is a `herestring`, which feeds the contents of `$line` to `xmllint` as stdin.

Comment: +1 for herestring, I've always done this as `while read line; do echo $line | xmllint...`

Comment: Previously the last line of the answer was written: while read line; do xmllint --format - <<<$line; done ... that worked fine for me... why was it changed and what's the difference?

Comment: @frankadelic it's almost always best to quote a variable when you use it, so Gilles added quotes here.

Comment: Right, but why was IFS= added? And what is read -r ?

Comment: @gilles before I posted, I checked and it didn't break on anything I could find without the quotes. Can you give an example that breaks an unquoted herestring?

Comment: @frankadelic `-r` prevents interpreting backslashes (`\ `) as escapes and prints them like any other character (which probably is what you want). `IFS` is the input field separator, setting it there makes sure it's not set to something unexpected, without changing it for later commands.

Comment: @frankadelic `-r` on `read` is the only change that's necessary here. Setting `IFS` to the empty string retains initial and trailing whitespace, which is a good habit to get into, even if it doesn't matter here because `xmllint` doesn't care about these. The double quotes around `$line` aren't necessary because no shell that supports `<<<` performs any expansion on it; again, double quotes around variable substitutions are a good habit to get into. See also [Why is `while IFS= read` used so often, instead of `IFS=; while read..`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18936)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with `xargs`, but `xargs` would pass each line as an argument to `xmllint`, not on its standard input. You would need to have `xargs` invoke a shell to feed the text to `xmllint`.

```
mysql … | xargs -L 1 sh -c 'echo "$0" | xmllint --format -'
```

A shell loop is the easiest method. The canonical way to loop over lines is [`while IFS= read -r line; do …`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18886/why-is-while-ifs-read-used-so-often-instead-of-ifs-while-read/18936#18936).

```
mysql … |
while IFS= read -r line; do printf '%s\n' "$line" | xmllint --format -; done
```