# Settings environment variables from a file

Tags: shell-script, environment-variables

I want to have a file (outside of git) that contains certain environment variables. While a script (which is in git) needs to read them and export to `env`.

My current implementation works for variables if the value does not contain spaces. Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

```
export $(cat .env | grep -v ^# | xargs -n 1)
```

My file looks like this:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS="127.0.0.1 dev.local localhost boot2docker"
```

While my environment only contains:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS=127.0.0.1
```

Note: I found a similar question: [Set Variable Environment Variables in bash (or other)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31797/set-variable-environment-variables-in-bash-or-other). However those answers don't seem to understand spaces in values either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your one sample line, it looks like your file may be in Bourne-like shell syntax.

So as your shell seems to be of the Bourne-type, you can just source the file after having issued a `set -a` so each new variable definition be automatically exported (assuming you do want them exported):

```
set -a
. ./.env
set +a
```

Comment: Sometimes there's a very elegant solution. Thank you!