# Grep a string with spaces from a file

Tags: bash, grep

```sh
#!/bin/bash
LIST=/errors_exception.txt
cd /test
for PATTERN in `cat $LIST`
do
        for FILE in $(ls)
        do
        if zcat $FILE | grep -Fxq "$PATTERN"; then
        echo "$PATTERN found pattern in $FILE" >> output
        fi
done
done
```

I'm trying to scan a lots of compressed log files (.gz) and check if the pattern I'm looking for is still exist on those logs.

For example in my code above, lets say, `errors_exception.txt` contains below

```
one 
one two three
four five
six
```

`/test` - dir contain log files

Why is it when I run the script, it doesn't read the 2nd line "one two three" as a single line?

When I run bash -x test.sh (name of the script) it reads the 2nd line like there's another 3 more line where in the text file it shows "one two three" as a single line.

Comment: Read [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Answer (score 3):

```
list=/errors_exception.txt
cd /test
while IFS= read -r pattern ; do
    for file in * ; do
        if zcat < "$file" | grep -Fxq "$pattern"; then
            echo "$pattern found pattern in $file"
        fi
    done
done <"$list" > output
```

Notes:

- Neither of the two lines below will do what you expect:

  ```
  for PATTERN in `cat $LIST`

  for FILE in $(ls)
  ```

  In both case, the shell does word splitting which you don't want.  The suggested code above avoids this.
- Is the file `errors_exception.txt` really in the root directory?
- I converted the variables to lower case.  This is the convention for user created variables.  This convention will prevent you from accidentally overwriting some critical shell parameter.

#### More on word splitting

When the shell executes:

```
for PATTERN in `cat $LIST`
```

it runs `cat $LIST`. When it does that, spaces, tabs, and carriage returns are all treated as the same thing: a word break.  So, effectively, after the word splitting, this line becomes:

```
for PATTERN in one one two three four five six
```

and, as the `for` loop executes, `PATTERN` is assigned sequentially to one, one, two, three, four, five, and six.

What you really want is for each line to be treated as a line.  This is why the `while read.... done<"$list"` construct is used instead: on each loop, it reads one whole line.

The same issue would happen with this line is any file names have spaces in them:

```
for FILE in $(ls)
```

The results of `ls` are substituted into the line and, if any file names have spaces, tabs, or carriage returns in them (all of these are legal characters), then the names are split into parts.   For example, in an otherwise empty directory create one file:

```
$ touch "a b c"
```

Now, run a `for` loop:

```
$ for file in $(ls); do echo $file; done
a
b
c
```

The `for` loops is run three times even though there is only one file.  That is because the file name has spaces and, after word splitting, the `for` loop gets three arguments: a, b, and c.

This is easily avoided.  Use instead:

```
for file in *
```

The shell is smart enough to keep each file name here in tact regardless of what characters are in its name.

#### Recursive Searching

If we also want to search subdirectories for gzipped files, then we can use bash's globstar feature as follows:

```
list=/errors_exception.txt
cd /test
shopt -s globstar
while IFS= read -r pattern ; do
    for file in **/*.gz ; do
        if zcat < "$file" | grep -Fxq "$pattern"; then
            echo "$pattern found pattern in $file"
        fi
    done
done <"$list" > output
```

This requires `bash`.

Comment: `<$list` not `<list`

Comment: yeah thanks, i actually notice that and correct it.

Comment: can you explain whats wrong in my code?

Comment: @nolram16 I updated the answer to talk more about that.

Comment: another question regarding this, what if the location of the log files has a sub-folder inside which contains logfiles also (.gz)

Comment: @nolram16 As it stands, files in subdirectories are not included.  Do you want them included?  All subdirectories or just specific ones?

Comment: yes i want to include them. all subdirectories which also contain log files.

Comment: i tried to replace * with ls -R but it shows 

zcat: <name of file> <name of pattern> 

which causes no file or directory error

Comment: can you put an explanation about IFS= read -r ?

thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I added a solution that looks in subdirectories. `IFS= read -r` helps assure that the line is read in unmangled.  See Giles's answer in this question for more details: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18936/53604

Comment: it still cant read files inside the subdirectories. any thoughts? i dont have enough reputation yet. i cant bring this up to chat

Comment: "cant read files inside the subdirectories" Does that mean permission was denied or what? If you run `shopt -s globstar; echo **/*.gz`, do you see all the files listed? (The system wouldn't let me move you to chat either.)