# While line read maintaining escaped spaces?

Tags: bash

I'm running a loop on each line in a file.

```
if [ -e "/tmp/history" ]; then
  while read line; do
    connect.sh $line \
      && break
  done </tmp/history
fi
```

The file is formatted like:

```
user\ name user\ password
```

So that each line will contain `$1` and `$2` for `connect.sh`.

Yet it seems with my while loop `$line` loses the line breaks before passing to `connect.sh` so that `user\ name` becomes `user name`.

Is there a way I can modify my while loop to maintain the line breaks?

Comment: You're only reading into one variable here, but if you ever tried to split the line into $user and $password, you'd want to clear IFS. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18936/117549

Comment: Also good reading: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/117549

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by adding the `-r` flag and double quoting the variable.

```
if [ -e "/tmp/history" ]; then
  while read -r line; do
    connect.sh "$line" \
      && break
  done <"/tmp/history"
fi
```

[Similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564778/bash-special-characters-lost-when-reading-file).

Comment: If you want to preserve leading/trailing/interior whitespace, use `while IFS= read -r line` -- this is the idiomatic way to read lines of a file absolutely verbatim.