# How to match name exactly with Bash's `help` builtin?

Tags: bash, documentation

It seems the Bash built-in help command `help` does some really strange globbing:

- `help read` shows the documentation for `read`, `readarray` and `readonly`.
- `help rea?` shows only the documentation for `read`.
- `help 'read$'` doesn't work.
- `help read | sed '/^read[^:]\+/,$d'` is just silly.

Is there some more intuitive way to get only the `read` output?

Comment: It seems they have fixed this annoying behaviour with the implicit `*` at the end if there is an exact match, (at least as of version version 4.3.42). In my version of bash `help read` shows only the documentation for `read`, but `help read` would show the documentation for `read`, `readarray`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems by defaul `help foo` is actually equivalent to `help foo*`.
But if some special globbing characters are used then the ending "`*`" is not implicitely added.

So, a possibility would be `help [r]ead`.

The globbing used is the one used by the shell for file matching; afaik there isn't any equivalent of `\<` nor `\>`.

Comment: It's globbing, just like filename completion, *but it is expanded after you enter it*, and I don't see anyway to control it (see `builtins/help.def`, it's a `for()` loop over all builtins). Since `[]` trumps `*`, `[r]ead` gets my vote. `read`, `time` and `type` are the only problematic complete commands (and the two types of `for` if you're a pedant).

Comment: Accepting since it also works for `help [s]et`.

Answer (score 0):

pipe the output of help through a small awk script:

```
help () {
    builtin help "$1" |
    awk -F: -v command="$1" '
        p && /^[^[:space:]]/ {exit}
        $1 == command {p = 1}
        p
    '
}
```

Now `help read` will only give you the help for the read builtin.