# Calling dir names from a paramater list file

Tags: shell, scripting, directory

Wondering if there is a best way to call directory names and iterate as parameter from a list.

Example

```
cat /dropbox/script/DirList.txt


DIR_A
DIR_B
DIR_C
DIR_D
```

```
/dropbox/dev/inbox/<DIR_A>/ *.*
/dropbox/dev/inbox/<DIR_B>/ *.*
/dropbox/dev/inbox/<DIR_C>/ *.*
/dropbox/dev/inbox/<DIR_D>/ *.*
```

considering folders/directories already exist If file exist in each of the mentioned directories then move them to outbox

`mv  /dropbox/dev/inbox/<DIR_D>/ *.* to /dropbox/dev/outbox/<DIR_D>/ *.*`

I tried

```
if [ -d /dropbox/dev/inbox/<DIR_D>/ ]; then
  mv  /dropbox/dev/inbox/<DIR_D>/ *.* to /dropbox/dev/outbox/<DIR_D>/ 
fi
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish.  Can you try to reword it some?

Comment: Do these directory names actually have `<`s and `>`s in them?

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish with `/dropbox/dev/inbox/<DIR_A>/ *.*` Did you intentionally put a space there?  Do you want to glob all files in that directory with an extension?

Comment: Looks like a job for `rsync --remove-source-files` to me.

Comment: dir names does not have <>

Comment: no space i am trying to move all the files in the dir if exist by using *.*

Comment: All files that exist in these folders trying to move to outbox if exist sorry if it is confusing, trying to explain with examples is getting complicated `/dropbox/dev/inbox/DIR_A/ 
/dropbox/dev/inbox/DIR_B/ 
/dropbox/dev/inbox/DIR_C/ 
/dropbox/dev/inbox/DIR_D/ `

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for looping over lines in a file:

```
while read dir_name; do
    cp -pR /dropbox/dev/inbox/$dir_name/* /dropbox/dev/outbox/$dir_name/
done < /dropbox/script/DirList.txt
```

You may need a `mkdir -p /dropbox/dev/outbox/$dir_name` in there if outbox directories don't already exist.

Comment: You many need to quote `$dir_name` in the `cp` (`"$dir_name"`).  You might also want `read -r` just in case there's a backslash in the file!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this should work.  Note that "*.*" only matches files with a period in the name (unlike Windows where it matches all files).

```
#!/bin/sh
INBOX=/dropbox/dev/inbox
OUTBOX=/dropbox/dev/outbox
for d in $(cat /dropbox/script/DirList.txt); do
    if [ -d $INBOX/$d ]; then
        mkdir -p $OUTBOX/$d
        mv $INBOX/$d/* $OUTBOX/$d/
    fi
done
```

Comment: `for d in $(cat ...)` needs some caveats - see for example [Reading lines from a file with bash: for vs. while](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24260/reading-lines-from-a-file-with-bash-for-vs-while)