# grep stringset as a single line

Tags: grep, line

Let say in a text file if I do

```
grep FINAL *.msg
```

it returns

```
FINAL   COMPUTATIONS:  Elapsed Time: 000:30:55.65; CPU Time: 000:30:26.53  
FINAL   COMPUTATIONS:  Elapsed Time: 000:28:11.77; CPU Time: 000:27:41.36
```

Now if I do for loop as

```
for line in `grep FINAL *.msg`
```

the `"$line"` does not consider `"FINAL   COMPUTATIONS:  Elapsed Time: 000:30:55.65; CPU Time: 000:30:26.53"` as a single line.

How I can solve this?

Comment: Related, I think: [Reading lines from a file with bash: for vs. while](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24260/reading-lines-from-a-file-with-bash-for-vs-while)

Comment: Your question reads to me like this could very well be a form of "XY Problem" (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  Please edit your question to show exactly what it is you are trying to _accomplish_ with your input data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DopeGhoti is absolutly right, here's something which fits probably a bit more. Read linewise from grep output (pattern applied to all *.msg files in current directory) with help of process subtitution:

```
i=0; 
while read -r line; do 
    echo $((i++)) "$line"; 
done < <(grep "FINAL" ./*.msg)
```

snippet is free of shellcheck warnings :)

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the way the shell is splitting your input.  Keep in mind that, unless told otherwise, any whitespace will generally split inputs:

```
$ echo "Foo bar baz"
Foo bar baz
$ for word in $(echo "Foo bar baz"); do echo $word; done
Foo
bar
baz
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My question, whatever is `grep` with FINAL (e.g. "FINAL   COMPUTATIONS:  Elapsed Time: 000:30:55.65; CPU Time: 000:30:26.53"), how I can loop so that `$line` returns complete line (not FINAL, COMPUTATIONS:, Elapsed, Time, etc. as separate lines)?