# Trouble getting awk output in for loop

Tags: bash, shell, text-processing, awk

I'm trying to create a script that will check a website for a word. I have a few to check so I'm trying to input them via another file.

The file is called "testurls". In the file I  list the keyword then the URL. They are separated with a semicolon.

```
Example Domains;www.example.com
Google;www.google.com
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

# Call list of keywords and urls
DATA=`cat testurls`

for keyurl in $DATA
do
    keyword=`awk -F ";" '{print $1}' $keyurl`
    url=`awk -F ";" '{print $2}' $keyurl`
    curl -silent $url | grep '$keyword' > /dev/null
 if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    # Fail
        echo "Did not find $keyword on $url"
    else
    # Pass
        echo $url "Okay"
fi
done
```

The output is:

```
awk: cannot open Example (No such file or directory)
awk: cannot open Example (No such file or directory)
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
Did not find  on
awk: cannot open Domains;www.example.com (No such file or directory)
awk: cannot open Domains;www.example.com (No such file or directory)
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
Did not find  on
awk: cannot open Google;www.google.com (No such file or directory)
awk: cannot open Google;www.google.com (No such file or directory)
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
Did not find  on
```

I've hacked away at this for ages now. Any help is very welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several problems with your script. I've listed the ones I found, but I haven't tested, there may be others.

`for keyurl in $DATA; do …` splits `$DATA` at each whitespace, not at each newline. So in the first iteration, `$DATA` will be `Example`; then `Domains;www.example.com`, and so on. Furthermore, each value undergoes wildcard expansion, so if there is a `*` in a keyword, you might see funky results depending on the files present in the current directory.

You're [tring to process newline-separated data](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9784/how-can-i-read-line-by-line-from-a-variable-in-bash/9831#9831). A simple way is

```
while read -r keyurl; do
  …
done <testurls
```

This strips the indentation from each line, which is probably not a bad thing here. (Use `IFS= read -r keyurl` if you want `keyurl` to contain each line exactly.)

Your calls to `awk` aren't working because you're passing `$keyurl` as a file name. You need to pass it as input instead. While you're at it, always use double quotes around variable substitutions (otherwise the shell performs some expansions on their value). I also recommend using `$(…)` instead of `` `…` ``; they're the same, exept that `` `…` `` is difficult to use when you want to quote things inside, whereas the syntax of `$(…)` is intuitive.

```
keyword=`echo "$keyurl" | awk -F ";" '{print $1}'`
url=`echo "$keyurl" | awk -F ";" '{print $2}'`
```

There's a better way to split a variable at the first semicolon: use the shell's built-in constructs to strip a prefix or suffix from a string.

```
keyword=${keyurl%%;*} url=${keyurl#*;}
```

But since your data comes from the `read` built-in and the separator is a single character, you can take advantage of the `IFS` feature and directly split your input as you read it.

```
while IFS=';' read -r keyword url; do …
```

Coming to your curl and grep calls, note that you're looking for the literal text `$keyword`, since you used single quotes. Use double quotes; note that the keyword will be interpreted as a [basic regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions). If you want the keyword to be interpreted as a literal string, pass the `-F` option to `grep`. You should also put `-e` before the pattern, in case the keyword begins with the character `-` (otherwise the keyword would be interpreted as an option to grep). Finally on the topic of grep, its `-q` option is equivalent to `>/dev/null`. Also remember the double quotes around `$url`.

```
curl -silent "$url" | grep -Fqe "$keyword"
```

You can shorten the `if [ $? != 0 ]; then` part by putting the command directly in there.

```
if curl -silent "$url" | grep -Fqe "$keyword"; then
```

In summary;

```
while IFS=';' read -r keyword url; do
  if curl -silent "$url" | grep -Fqe "$keyword"; then
    echo "Did not find $keyword on $url"
  else
    echo $url "Okay"
  fi
done
```

Comment: You really should consider collecting some of your answers and publishing them in the one place. You could call it `Unix: breakfast of champignons`

Comment: I absolutely agree. It would be an amazing guide for beginners like me. :) +1 (Too bad I can't vote it as THE best answer)

Comment: +1 I was not expecting an answer like this! Thank you for taking the time to show me what I was doing wrong and explaining how to do it right (and in a good level of detail!).

Answer (score 1):

awk is considering value of $keyurl as data file to be processed. You need to feed value of $keyurl to awk like

```
keyword=`echo $keyurl | awk -F ";" '{print $1}'`
```

This will solve your one of your many problems.

Comment: This is the basic problem causing the errors, but it's [not the only one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25285/trouble-getting-awk-output-in-for-loop/25301#25301).

Answer (score 0):

If the format of `testurls` is consistent, you could use a simpler approach:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
    keyword="${line%;*}"
    url="${line#*;}"
    curl -silent "$url" | grep "$keyword" >/dev/null
    [ $? = 0 ] && echo "${keyword} found" || echo "Fail..."
done < testurls
```