# How to avoid a useless use of cat when parsing a file?

Tags: shell, ksh, cat

I have a file containing a list of directories. For instance

```
/foo/bar/dir1
/foo/bar/dir2
/foo/bar/dir3
```

I want to create all these directories. Here's what I did:

```
for dir in $(cat myfile); do mkdir $dir; done
```

What would be the correct way of doing this while avoiding the "useless use of cat"?

Ideally, answers would focus on Ksh88, but I'm also interested in other shells

Comment: if all the directories are under single directory and are few then use brace expansion of shell. `$ mkdir /foo/bar/dir{1,2,3}` or `$ mkdir /foo/bar/{dir1,dir2,dir3}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I read line by line from a variable in bash?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9784/how-can-i-read-line-by-line-from-a-variable-in-bash)

Comment: Thanks Gilles for pointing out that question, I was not aware of it. For the record, I was looking to read from a file not a variable. And my question is shell-agnostic (if anything I mention `ksh`). In any case I found my answer; I was not familiar with `read`. The man page will do the rest.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

AProgrammer's suggestion of using `xargs` is often best, but another option is to use redirection into a `while` loop, which allows additional commands to be made and variables to be set:

```
while read -r dir; do mkdir $dir; done < myfile
```

An example of a more complicated structure would be:

```
now=`date +%Y%m%d.%H%M%S`
while read -r dir; do
    newdistfile="/tmp/dist-`echo $dir | tr / _`.tgz"
    mv $dir ~/backups/$dir.$now &&
        mkdir $dir &&
        tar xzfC $newdistfile $dir
done < myfile
```

This is not something that `xargs` could do without writing a 'helper program'.

Comment: What are the limits of using `xargs` over `read`? It is my understanding that `xargs` will fork a new process (unlike `read` that is a shell builtin). Isn't this something you want to avoid?

Comment: `xargs` will operate on a single command, so if you want to have a compound statement (like more than one, an `if`, `while` or `for`, etc.) or setting a variable, then you cannot use `xargs`.  Yes, xargs will fork one new statement, plus one for some number of input lines, which is very little overhead. However, some older versions of `xargs` do not take a `-0` option, so a `while read` will be the way to go if there may be whitespace in the input directory names.

Answer (score 12):

I'd do something like

```
xargs mkdir < myfile
```

Comment: Why "-n 1"? You can do several directories with one invocation of mkdir.

Comment: @ddeimeke, because I didn't remember if it is POSIX or just a common extension.  Now I've checked and it is in SUSv2.

Comment: Useless use of xargs. ;)

Comment: Note that this assumes that the directory names _are quoted_ in the input file if they contain whitespaces.

Answer (score 12):

At least in bash, as long as there are no filenames containing spaces and newlines, this:

```
mkdir $(< myfile)
```

works. So we have a useless use of `for`, `xargs` too.

< does not start a new process in bash, in contrast to `cat`, but I don't know for `ksh`.

Comment: +1 for clarifying, as opposed to other answer, the spaces problem.

Answer (score 4):

This is the solution closer to your original script still avoiding the useless cat

```
for dir in $(<myfile); do mkdir $dir; done
```

It still contains a useless loop though.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't say that's a useless use of cat.

In the [classic sense](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html), a UUOC means writing:

```
cat file | some_command and its args ...
```

instead of the equivalent and cheaper

```
<file some_command and its args ...
```

or (equivalently and more classically)

```
some_command and its args ... < file
```

In this case:

```
for dir in $(cat myfile); do mkdir $dir; done
```

there is no command into which the output of `cat` is being piped.

There are certainly alternatives that don't use `cat`.  In particular, for bash and ksh `$(<myfile)` is likely to be faster than `$(cat myfile)`, though not all shells support that construct.  But I wouldn't call the original code a "useless use of cat" any more than I'd call AProgrammer's solution a "useless use of xargs".

Answer (score 1):

With `bash` 4 and limited by `ARG_MAX`

```
mapfile -t <file && mkdir -- "${MAPFILE[@]}"
```

Comment: or `zmodload zsh/mapfile && mkdir -- ${(f)mapfile[infile]}` if the shell is `zsh`

Answer (score 0):

Yours is a perfect example of intended POSIX usage of a while-loop, specifically what I call a "While Redirect".

**"While Redirect"**

```
while read dir
do
  mkdir $dir
done < myfile
```

Now, compare the previous example to what I call a "While Pipe":

**"While Pipe"**

```
cat myfile | while read dir
do
  mkdir $dir
done
```

The `cat` is not an UUoC in the While Pipe; it is part of the command syntax.  Just like you might have used `grep -E . myfile | while` or something else.

It is considered Useless in the **for-loop** mostly because it --in conjunction with the backquotes-- is considered to be inefficient and dangerous there.

[See here for more details](https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award#backticks)