# Can I access Nth line number of standard output?

Tags: bash, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, stdout, efficiency

Assuming a script that outputs a list of files:

```
$> bash someScript.sh
path/to/some/file
path/to/the/file/i/want/to/work/with
path/to/yet/another/file
```

Now I want to have the second file-path as parameter for another command, e.g. `vim`. Is there a way to directly access it?

And I want to point out that I do not necessarily want to access the second file, but the next time it could be the third or the 27th. I want to be able to select that Nth line as easily as possible.

Right now I do mouse-selecting and insert by middle-clicking or type the path with tab-completion. Now I wonder if there is an easier way.

Problem with my own solution is though that I would have to edit all my scripts this way. It would be fun if there was a more general solution to this issue, that would work with any kind of command, e.g. `find`.

Comment: In case you feel like trying to parse `ls` output, read [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) first.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022384/bash-tool-to-get-nth-line-from-a-file

Answer (score 55):

Sure.

```
bash someScript.sh | sed -n '2 p'
```

will filter your output and just print the second line of it. To make that a parameter to `vim`:

```
vim "$(bash someScript.sh | sed -n '2 p')"
```

Comment: awk way: `awk 'NR==2'` instead of `sed -n '2 p'`

Comment: As the question is tagged [tag:efficiency], better stop `sed` ASAP: `sed -n '2{p;q}'`. This avoids reading the remainder of output in vain. @Benoit, similarly for `awk`: `awk 'NR==2{print;exit}`.

Answer (score 18):

Use head and tail, e.g. accessing the 2nd line of an output:

```
bash someScript.sh | head -2 | tail -1
```

Comment: `tail +N | head -n 1` works better because if `N` is greater than the total lines, it outputs nothing, instead of the last line

Answer (score 4):

If being short to type is paramount and the file isn't very large:

```
nth_line=$(sed -n ${n}p)
nth_line=$(sed $n\!d)
```

If the file is long and you're only interested in one line, use `sed` to print the desired line and quit, or `tail` to remove the previous lines and `head` to extract the first line of the result.

```
nth_line=$(sed -n -e "$n {" -e p -e q -e "}")
nth_line=$(tail -n +$n | head -n 1)
```

(Note that `tail -n +$n` skips n-1 lines, i.e. its output starts with the nth line.)

For a small number of lines, you can use the `read` built-in.

```
IFS= read -r first_line; IFS= read -r second_line
```

If you want to read all lines, you can put them in an array (ksh/bash/zsh only).

```
IFS=$'\n'
lines=($(cat))
second_file="${lines[1]}"  # note that ksh/bash arrays start at 0
```

If you want to make this reusable code, put it in a function.

```
# Read at most MAX input lines (default: all) into the VAR array (default: ${lines[@]}).
# Usage: read_lines [VAR [MAX]]
read_lines () {
  typeset IFS=$'\n'
  if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then set lines; fi
  if [ -z "$2" ]; then eval "$1=(\$(cat))"; else eval "$1=(\$(head -n $2))"; fi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below are the two better ways to print nth line of text files in linux.

1. Use the combination of `head` and `tail` command

   One of the easiest way of printing nth line of a text file is by using the combination of head and tail command.Below is an exapmle of how to use it for displaying the 9th line of a file named `sample.txt`

   ```
   cat sample.txt | head -9 | tail -1
   ```

   If you want to display 9th and 10th line replace the value of tail to 2 as below.

   ```
   cat sample.txt | head -9 | tail -2
   ```
2. using `sed` command

   There are two ways to do this with `sed` command. One is with using `p` (print) and other is with using `d` (delete) along with `sed` command. Following are the examples

   ```
   cat sample.txt | sed -n '9p'     # This will display the 9th line of sample.txt file
   cat sample.txt | sed -n '9p;12p' # This will display 9th and 12th line of  sample.txt
   ```

   Likewise we can display as much of line of a file as per our need.

   ```
   cat sample.txt | sed '9!d'       # This will display the 9th line of sample.txt
   ```

http://tecmint4u.blogspot.com/2020/10/how-to-get-nth-line-of-text-file-in.html

Answer (score 0):

I solved it even though it's a bit hackish ;)

That's the script outputting file paths:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm /tmp/svn_filelist_to_source /tmp/svn_filelist
svn status | egrep 'M |A ' | cut -c9- > /tmp/svn_filelist
counter=1
cat /tmp/svn_filelist | while read -r path; do
  echo $path
  echo "file$counter=\"$path\"" >> /tmp/svn_filelist_to_source
  counter=$(($counter+1))
done;
```

Here's how I run it, which I think I'll put in an alias:

```
sh statusAddedAndModified.sh && source /tmp/svn_filelist_to_source
```

Now I can:

`svn commit $file2`

Comment: Use `IFS= read -r` unless you mean to strip leading and trailing whitespace ([explanation](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9831)). There are shorter and faster ways to grab all lines; see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

*Read 2nd line (zero-index == 1):*

```perl
raku -ne '.put if $++ == 1'

#OR:

raku -e 'lines[1].put'
```

---

*Read line# determined by `env` variable:*

```perl
env desired_line="1" raku -ne '.put if $++ == %*ENV<desired_line> ;'

#OR: 

env desired_line="1" raku -e 'lines[ %*ENV<desired_line> ].put;'
```

Above are answers written in Raku, a member of the Perl family of programming languages. Input is taken either via STDIN, or off the command line (both answers). In the first set

In the first set of answers, line number is hard-coded. In the second set of answers, the line number can be determined from a shell variable. Raku has a special associative array `%*ENV` which can be used to access shell variables.

Raku has an `awk`-like mode invoked with the `-ne` command-lane flags. Here, anonymous pre-incrementing  (`++$`) or post-incrementing (`$++`) variables can be used to count line numbers (and many other things as well).

Using the OP's example input:

```
~$ printf 'path/to/some/file\npath/to/the/file/i/want/to/work/with\npath/to/yet/another/file' | raku -e 'lines[1].put'
path/to/the/file/i/want/to/work/with
```

OR:

```
~$ printf 'path/to/some/file\npath/to/the/file/i/want/to/work/with\npath/to/yet/another/file' | env desired_line="1" raku -e 'lines[ %*ENV<desired_line> ].put'
path/to/the/file/i/want/to/work/with
```

Finally, see ["Raku Input/Output: the definitive guide"](https://docs.raku.org/language/io-guide) on how to use Raku to extract/grep target lines, words, etc., from files that are too big to fit into RAM.

https://docs.raku.org/routine/lines
https://raku.org