# bash: Some issue when using read <<<"$VARIABLE" on a read-only root partition. Any known workarounds?

Tags: bash, readonly, tmp, here-document, read

Just by coincidence I had to use my ATA-ID-to-device-name script (found here: https://serverfault.com/questions/244944/linux-ata-errors-translating-to-a-device-name/426561#426561) on a **read-only** `/` partition. In case you're curious, it was an Ubuntu recovery console which will let you access your `/` partition, but will mount it read-only by default. I am glad about that, because otherwise I would probably never have found out that my script behaves strangely on a R/O system due to a specific line, this one:

```
IFS=: read HostMain HostMid HostSub <<< "$HostFull"
```

This does *not* work if there is no write permission. I wouldn't have assumed it would fail, though. But apparently the `<<<` operator *does* require to write some temporary file to somewhere.

But is there any way to circumvent the creation of a temporary file, or, is there any way to specify where the file is written to? In the Ubuntu recovery console, there is---oddly enough---write permission on the `/run` directory, so that would do, if I could somehow "tell" `read` to write the temp file to somewhere else than usual.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf No, “opening a file descriptor” wouldn't be a problem (why would it?), and `/dev/fd` has nothing to do with this. `<<<` is the culprit though, because it creates a temporary file (which needs to be written somewhere).

Answer (score 8):

An array could make the string parsing without the need for a temporal file. Don't forget to turn off globbing.

```
set -f
IFS=: Hosts=($HostFull)
HostMain=${Hosts[0]}
HostMid=${Hosts[1]}
HostSub=${Hosts[2]}
set +f
```

Comment: or even without `IFS`, if you're sure there are no spaces in `$HostFull` as so: `Hosts=( ${HostFull//:/ } )`. Or even if there are spaces: `HostMain=${HostFull%%:*}; HostMid=${HostFull#*:}; HostSub=${HostMid#*:}; HostMid=${HostMid%:*}` (or something similar, I'm getting confused `:D`).

Comment: You are right, as you show parameter expansion is tricky bussines...

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @gniourf_gniourf, your probably needing write access but not to the file descriptors, most likely a file.

You could test this by tracing the execution of your command when in the readonly partition.

```
{ strace -p "$$" & sleep 1; read var1 <<< "hi"; sleep 1; kill "$1"; }
```

The above will run `strace` on the Bash shell (process `$$`). It then sleeps for 1 second, and then runs the `read` from the HERE STRING. I've put the string `"hi"` in this position. I then `sleep` for one more second and then `kill` the `strace`.

#### Example

While parsing this output you'll notice that a file is opened as `O_WRONLY`, which is for writing to a file.

```
open("/tmp/sh-thd-4137571604", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL|O_TRUNC, 0600) = 3
```

Above we can see what file is being written to by your command sequence.

Comment: Not to “create the file descriptors” (that doesn't make any sense). To create the *file*. It isn't `read` that opens a file for writing (that would be silly), it's `<<<`.

Comment: @Gilles - thanks, I didn't quite understand what it was telling me. Cleaned up the A.

Comment: Thank you very much! A very nice technique, which might even help me multiple times in the future with similar issues. However, one thing *is* worrying me, and that is the fact that `/tmp` is a __hardcoded__ path. And probably you've guessed it, `/tmp` *IS* there already, but read-only as well! And since working on that recovery console will have me logged into my __live__ file system, I would not want to mess in there by symlinking or whatever (not even while in that console).

Answer (score 3):

I find positional parameters very useful for this kind of task.  It's generally portable to all shells as well, and costs no forks nor temporary files.

```
$ HostFull=main:mid:sub    
$ oldIFS=$IFS; IFS=:; set -- $HostFull; IFS=$oldIFS
$ echo $1
main
$ echo $2
mid
$ echo $3
sub
```

Comment: A good approach! Thank you. Plus, I like it that it does not require any external tools (that we are usually not to be expected to find in those restricted environments anyhow). The only thing that *may* cause some trouble is the `$1`, `$2`, `$3` stuff: remember that in a script, this will usually stand for an argument passed to the script *itself*. -- And while we're at it: if IFS is meant to be a space, *IFS= * will not do in this syntax; you will have to specify __IFS=' '__ explicitly.