# How do I delete all of a set of files in a random order?

Tags: bash, shell-script, files

I have a set of files, all that are named with the convention `file_[number]_[abcd].bin` (where [number] is a number in the range 0-size of drive in MB). i.e there is `file_0_a.bin`, `file_0_b.bin`, `file_0_c.bin` and `file_0_d.bin` and then the `0` would become a `1` and so on.

The number of files is figured out at run-time based on the size of the partition. I need to delete all of the files that have been created, but in a pseudo-random manner. **in blocks of size that I need to be able to specify**, i.e where there is 1024 files, delete 512, then delete another 512.

I have the following function for doing it currently, which I call the required number of times, but it will get progressively less likely to find a file that exists, to the point where it might never complete. Obviously, this is somewhat less than ideal.

What is another method that I can use to delete all of the files in a random order?

```
deleteRandFile() #$1 - total number of files
{
    i=$((RANDOM%$1))
    j=$((RANDOM%3))
    file=""

    case $j in
    0)
        file="${dest_dir}/file_${i}_a.bin";;
    1)
        file="${dest_dir}/file_${i}_b.bin";;    
    2)
        file="${dest_dir}/file_${i}_c.bin";;
    3)
        file="${dest_dir}/file_${i}_d.bin";;
    esac

    if ! [[ -f $file ]]; then
        deleteRandFile $1
    else
        rm $file
    fi

    return 0;
}
```

Edit:
I'm trying to delete in random order so that I can fragment the files as much as possible. This is part of a script that begins by filling a drive with 1MB files, and deletes them, 1024 at a time, then fills the 'gap' with 1 1GB file. Rinse and repeat until you have some very fragmented 1GB files.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you can explain why it matters in what order you delete the files.

Comment: @NateEldredge Sure, uh...I'm trying to fragment a hard drive and kill a file system. I have my reasons.

Comment: In zsh, you would use the `*.bin(o+functionName)` notation as in http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9831

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to delete *all* the files, then, on a GNU system, you could do:

```
cd -P -- "$destdir" &&
  printf '%s\0' * | # print the list of files as zero terminated records
    sort -Rz |      # random sort (shuffle) the zero terminated records
    xargs -r0 rm -f # pass the input if non-empty (-r) understood as 0-terminated
                    # records (-0) as arguments to rm -f
```

If you want to only delete a certain number of those matching a regexp you'd insert something like this between the `sort` and `xargs`:

```
awk -v RS='\0' -v ORS='\0' -v n=1024 '/regexp/ {print; if (--n == 0) exit}'
```

With `zsh`, you could do:

```
shuffle() REPLY=$RANDOM
rm -f file_<->_[a-d].bin(.+shuffle[1,1024])
```

Comment: I don't suppose you'd mind explaining a bit more fully?

Comment: I need to learn to type faster, or ignore the review queues to get an answer in ;-)

Comment: This looks pretty good, do you mind going into a bit more detail about what the `xargs -r0` flag does?

Comment: Thanks, the last thing is how would I need to alter this to make it not delete the lot at once, but delete, say, 1024 at a time? Would piping it through something to get the first 1024 entries that match a regex work?

Comment: Awesome, that's perfect. Barring something that does it in fewer commands, I'll accept this in a little bit.

Comment: I wound out modifying this slightly to become the command `ls -l | sort -Rz | awk -v n=0 '/file_[0-9]+_[abcd].bin/ { if( ++n <= 1024) {print $9 ; }}' | xargs -r0 rm -f`

Comment: I wonder why you prefer to use "printf" here, instead of a `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0` ? (Just reading, as I can not test (no gnu here... :( ), but printf here apparently only add 1 NUL to the entire list of files (all on 1 line, if none have newlines embedded)? Isn't it prone to errors if files have spaces/newlines etc in their pathname? Please explain why this works :) and does sort -Rz shuffle also inside each (here possibly only 1) line?

Comment: @OlivierDulac, no. `printf '%s\0' *` formats each argument as `%s\0` so is like `find` except that it excludes dot files, sorts the list, doesn't fork a process. And you can do `printf '%s\0' file_*_[a-d].bin`. `find` may be better if you only want regular files though you could also use zsh and its globbing qualifiers.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: thanks a lot, quite handy trick indeed (if files are not too numerous to fit). I didn't knew `printf '%s' *` would "loop" over all files, i thought it would try to fit it all in a single %s. thx!

Comment: @OlivierDulac, `printf` is built in most shells, so there's no limit on the number of arguments (other than the available memory).

Answer (score 11):

Here's a potential alternative using `find` and `shuf`:

```
$ find $destdir -type f | shuf | xargs rm -f
```

This will find all the files in `$destdir` and then use the `shuf` command to shuffle their order, and then pass the list on to `xargs rm -f` for deletion.

To gate how many files are deleted:

```
$ find $destdir -type f | shuf | head -X | xargs rm -f
```

Where `-X` is the number of files that you want to delete, for example, `head -100`.

Comment: It's a good answer, but it doesn't let me specify how many files to delete. (also I don't have `shuf` on the system, but I didn't specify what I had, so that doesn't stop this being a good answer)

Comment: I'm confused, why do you need to specify a number to the delete function?

Comment: I want to delete the first `n` files in the shuffled list. I'll edit the question to make that more clear.

Comment: @Yann4 - like that?

Comment: Exactly like that. At the moment, the other answer wins out for me, as it doesn't involve re-compiling a kernel, but this is still a great answer, does exactly the job, +1.

Comment: Although, having said that, it doesn't let me match the file name to a regex, it'll just delete everything in the folder. But that could be altered by `find -regex` right?

Comment: @Yann4 - correct, this was to model an approach, you tune it however you need it. Remember it's just a list of files coming through the pipe, so you can insert a `grep -E 'pat1|pat2'` in the pipe chain too, to get which files you want. But it would be most efficient to do this on `find`.

Comment: @Yann4 I'm confused but curious about that "doesn't involve re-compiling a kernel" - is that some kind of meme I missed?

Comment: @VolkerSiegel I'm working on an embedded environment, and while the various stuff *runs*, I had to recompile it to get bash and awk, as that counts as an extra. Although, I could roll with that being a meme

Comment: This answer is unsafe as written, at least in general. `find` outputs literal strings separated by newlines, and `xargs` reads a *shell-quoted, whitespace-delimited* list of names as input. A malicious name in the input can trick it into deleting something very different from what you intended to delete.

Comment: @R - look at the requirements for the format of filenames that the OP is using. This is perfectly safe given that!

Comment: @slm, that is no excuse for writing incorrect code or not pointing out the limitations.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - I disagree. If the requirements are stipulated that code only needs to deal with X then it should be perfectly fine for that code to deal with X. The OP even leads with this information as the first sentence.