# How to get a list to be entered in quotes

Tags: bash, shell, text-processing, quoting

I have a script that runs a python script (used to deduplicate emails via IMAP) after a user has entered a servername, username & password.
The first part of it gets a list of folders which the second part then uses as inputs - all fine unless a folder name has a space in it at which point the entry needs to be in quotation marks
As an example Inbox is fine whereas My Inbox needs to be read as "My Inbox"

```
#!/bin/sh
# Delete all duplicate messages in all folders of said account.
# Note that we connect through SSL (-x) to the default port.

read -p "Server: " SERVER
read -p "Username: " USER
read -s -p "Password: " PASS
echo
echo ...........
echo FOLDER LIST
echo ...........
echo

# Next line generates list for display only

/tmp/IMAPdedup-master/imapdedup.py -s $SERVER -x -u $USER -w $PASS -l

# Next line generates list to be used by the do line - this is the entries that need 
to have each line in quotations

for folder in `/tmp/IMAPdedup-master/imapdedup.py -s $SERVER -x -u $USER -w $PASS -l`;

do /tmp/IMAPdedup-master/imapdedup.py -s $SERVER -x -u $USER -w $PASS $folder

done
```

Comment: Do they really need to be quoted - or do they just need to be not split? See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Comment: No the need to be quoted as it will go down the list happily processing any folders without spaces (I presume this is a whitespace ?) in their names - including subfolders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the names to be quoted, you need the *variables* to be quoted. Specifically, to make your script work, you need to replace the `for folder in ...` loop with:

```
/tmp/IMAPdedup-master/imapdedup.py -s "$SERVER" -x -u "$USER" -w "$PASS" -l | 
while IFS= read -r folder; do 
 /tmp/IMAPdedup-master/imapdedup.py -s "$SERVER" -x -u "$USER" -w "$PASS" "$folder"
done
```

I suggest you read the following posts to understand why:

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/22222)
- [Reading lines from a file with bash: for vs. while](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/24260/22222)
- [How can I read line by line from a variable in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9784/22222)